# SimpleInjector HowTo Register multiple Open Generic Interfaces for a Single Generic Implementation

Tags: c#, generics, simple-injector, open-generics

I'm trying to get started with SimpleInjector as an IOC Container and up to now I'm pretty happy with it. But right now I'm stuck on a problem I can't solve. I searched on SO and in the documentation, but it seems to be not answered yet. I've seen [the howto doc from SimpleInjector](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/howto.html#register-multiple-interfaces-with-the-same-implementation) but that doesn't cover open generic interfaces.

I have two generic interfaces like these:

```
public interface IEventPublisher<TEvent>
{
   void Publish(TEvent Event);
}
public interface IEventSubscriber<TEvent>
{
    void Subscribe(Action<TEvent> CallBack);
}
```

And one open generic implementation for those two:

```
class EventMediator<T> : IEventPublisher<T>, IEventSubscriber<T>
{
    List<Action<T>> Subscriptions = new List<Action<T>>();

    public void Publish(T Event)
    {
        foreach (var Subscription in this.Subscriptions)
            Subscription.Invoke(Event);
    }

    public void Subscribe(Action<T> CallBack)
    {
        this.Subscriptions.Add(CallBack);
    }
}
```

In my Application I'm setting up SimpleInjector like this:

```
this.Container = new SimpleInjector.Container();
this.Container.RegisterOpenGeneric(typeof(IEventPublisher<>), typeof(EventMediator<>), Lifestyle.Singleton);
this.Container.RegisterOpenGeneric(typeof(IEventSubscriber<>), typeof(EventMediator<>), Lifestyle.Singleton);
this.Container.Verify();
```

What I'm trying to archive is:
I'd like to get exactly the same instance when asking for a IEventPublisher or an IEventSubscriber. And furthermore this Instance shall be a singleton for any T.

I've tested this with these lines:

```
class DummyEvent {}

var p = this.Container.GetInstance<IEventPublisher<DummyEvent>>();
var s = this.Container.GetInstance<IEventSubscriber<DummyEvent>>();
var areSame = (object.ReferenceEquals(p,s));
```

Unfortunatly p and s don't refer to the same instance. Anyone happens to know a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are certain solutions for this, here's one: Create separate implementations for `IEventPublisher<T>` and `IEventSubscriber<T>` and let them delegate to the `EventMediator<T>`. For instance with these implementations:

```
public class EventPublisher<TEvent> : IEventPublisher<TEvent>
{
    private readonly EventMediator<TEvent> mediator;
    public EventPublisher(EventMediator<TEvent> mediator) {
        this.mediator = mediator;
    }

    public void Publish(TEvent Event) {
        this.mediator.Publish(Event);
    }
}

public class EventSubscriber<TEvent> : IEventSubscriber<TEvent>
{
    private readonly EventMediator<TEvent> mediator;
    public EventSubscriber(EventMediator<TEvent> mediator) {
        this.mediator = mediator;
    }

    public void Subscribe(Action<TEvent> CallBack) {
        this.mediator.Subscribe(Callback);
    }
}
```

Now you make the registrations as follows:

```
container.RegisterSingleOpenGeneric(typeof(EventMediator<>), typeof(EventMediator<>));
container.RegisterSingleOpenGeneric(typeof(IEventPublisher<>), typeof(EventPublisher<>));
container.RegisterSingleOpenGeneric(typeof(IEventSubscriber<>), typeof(EventSubscriber<>));
```

Now both the `EventPublisher<DummyEvent>` and `EventSubscriber<DummyEvent>` will point at the same `EventMediator<DummyEvent>` instance.

Another way to achieve this without the extra type is to make use of the `ResolveUnregisteredType` event (which is what the `RegisterOpenGeneric` extension method itself uses under the covers). Your configuration would look like this:

```
container.RegisterSingleOpenGeneric(typeof(EventMediator<>), typeof(EventMediator<>));

container.ResolveUnregisteredType += (s, e) =>
{
    if (e.UnregisteredServiceType.IsGenericType)
    {
        var def = e.UnregisteredServiceType.GetGenericTypeDefinition();

        if (def == typeof(IEventPublisher<>) || def == typeof(IEventSubscriber<>))
        {
            var mediatorType = typeof(EventMediator<>)
                .MakeGenericType(e.UnregisteredServiceType.GetGenericArguments()[0]);
            var producer = container.GetRegistration(mediatorType, true);
            e.Register(producer.Registration);
        }
    }
};
```

You could even extract this code into a more general extension method. This way your registration would look like this:

```
container.RegisterSingleOpenGeneric(typeof(EventMediator<>), typeof(EventMediator<>));
container.ForwardOpenGenericTo(typeof(IEventPublisher<>), typeof(EventMediator<>));
container.ForwardOpenGenericTo(typeof(IEventSubscriber<>), typeof(EventMediator<>));
```

The extension method would look like this:

```
public static void ForwardOpenGenericTo(this Container container,
    Type openGenericServiceType, Type openGenericServiceTypeToForwardTo)
{
    container.ResolveUnregisteredType += (s, e) =>
    {
        var type = e.UnregisteredServiceType;
        if (type.IsGenericType)
        {
            if (type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == openGenericServiceType)
            {
                var forwardToType = openGenericServiceTypeToForwardTo.MakeGenericType(
                    type.GetGenericArguments());
                var producer = container.GetRegistration(forwardToType, true);
                e.Register(producer.Registration);
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Hi Steven, thank you a lot. This actually works and solves my issue although I'd imagined there would be a way archiving this without creating separate implementations.

Comment: @ka: but do note that I do agree with Qujck about the separation in your design. I think your design improves with his suggestion.

Comment: Agreed. Both answers are correct and highly appreciated. Anyway, the initial question has been best answered by you.

Answer (score 3):

You are registering `IEventPublisher` and `IEventSubscriber` as separate singletons. You will need to refactor your code in one way or another. One solution is to separate the 3 responsibilities of your mediator:

The **Subscriber**

```
public interface IEventSubscriber<TEvent>
{
    void Subscribe(Action<TEvent> CallBack);
}

public class EventSubscriber<T> : IEventSubscriber<T>
{
    public readonly ISubscriptions<T> subscriptions;

    public EventSubscriber(ISubscriptions<T> subscriptions)
    {
        this.subscriptions = subscriptions;
    }

    public void Subscribe(Action<T> CallBack)
    {
        this.subscriptions.Add(CallBack);
    }
}
```

The **Publisher**

```
public interface IEventPublisher<TEvent>
{
    void Publish(TEvent Event);
}

public class EventPublisher<T> : IEventPublisher<T>
{
    public readonly ISubscriptions<T> subscriptions;

    public EventPublisher(ISubscriptions<T> subscriptions)
    {
        this.subscriptions = subscriptions;
    }

    public void Publish(T Event)
    {

        foreach (var subscription in this.subscriptions)
        {
            subscription.Invoke(Event);
        }
    }
}
```

The **Subscriptions**

```
public interface ISubscriptions<T> : IList<Action<T>> { }

public class Subscriptions<T> : List<Action<T>>, ISubscriptions<T> { }
```

Only the subscriptions need to be registered as singleton

```
var container = new Container();
container.RegisterOpenGeneric(typeof(IEventSubscriber<>), typeof(EventSubscriber<>));
container.RegisterOpenGeneric(typeof(IEventPublisher<>), typeof(EventPublisher<>));
container.RegisterSingleOpenGeneric(typeof(ISubscriptions<>), typeof(Subscriptions<>));
container.Verify();

var p = container.GetInstance<IEventPublisher<DummyEvent>>();
var s = container.GetInstance<IEventSubscriber<DummyEvent>>();
Assert.That(
    (p as EventPublisher<DummyEvent>).subscriptions  == 
    (s as EventSubscriber<DummyEvent>).subscriptions);
```

Comment: Hi qujck. Your approach is much like Stevens, although it's a bit cleaner through the separation of the concerns.